# Invoke-AzVMRunCommand as a job

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to use Invoke-AzVMRunCommand as a job. when I executed below script the job is created and executed successfully but I am failing to write the output like which job result belongs to which vm.

Comment: Post the script.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand is used to invoke a command on a particular VM. You should have this information beforehand.

Here is some information on `-AsJob` parameter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-2.6.0#parameters

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by AmanGarg-MSFT, you should have that information before hand. You can use a hashtable $Jobs to store the server name and Invoke-AzVMRunCommand output and later iterate through using the $Jobs.GetEnumerator().

```
$Jobs = @{}
$Servers = "Server01","Server02"
[System.String]$ScriptBlock = {Get-Process}
$FileName = "RunScript.ps1"
Out-File -FilePath $FileName -InputObject $ScriptBlock -NoNewline
$Servers | ForEach-Object {
    $vm = Get-AzVM -Name $_
    $Jobs.Add($_,(Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $_ -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $FileName -AsJob))
}
```